# NFL playoff probabilities

Tags: probability

The NFL has 32 teams split into 2 conferences of 16 team. Each conference has 4 divisions, with 4 teams in each division (the teams in each division stay the same each year). In each conference, the top team from each division and 2 wildcard teams (top two teams from the remaining teams) go to the playoffs. What is the probability that the two teams are from the same division?

Comment: Are you asking what is the probability that the two wild card teams are from the same division?  What are your assumptions about the results of the games-are they a random coin flip or are some teams better than others?  Do you want to account for the fact that teams in the same division play each other twice, which decreases the chance that the wild card teams come from the same division?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not susceptible to a closed-form solution but you could simulate it to any level of "realism" you desired. This could include varying probabilities for each game (modelling form/skill) plus probabilities for ties.

The end results depend on the results of **all** the teams in each conference and **some** of the results from the other conference. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462445/whats-the-probability-that-an-nfl-team-with-a-given-win-loss-record-makes-the-p?rq=1) question for some of the details.

**Edit**

So, having simulated 10,000 seasons with 0 chance of a tie and an equal chance for each team to win any game, there were 4,895 occasions (out of 20,000 - remember each season has 2 conferences) where the wildcards came from the same division or about 25%.

I have put the full results at the other question.

Answer (score 0):

There are 12 non-division winners in each conference. Choose the first wildcard from any division. There are two remaining teams in that division, and nine in other divisions.

Comment: so would it be 4(4 choose 1)(2/9)

Comment: You're over thinking it. You asked what the chances are that both teams came from the same division, not a specific division. The first wildcard has to come from some division, so all you need to do is compute the probability that the second team cones from the first team's division.

Comment: I don't think it is this simple.  There is anticorrelation in the divisions of the wild card teams, as the third place team in the division that has your first pick has to beat the second place teams in the other divisions.

Comment: Yes, it becomes more complicated when you factor in the schedule and tie breakers and such. However, I'm not sure it's an interesting endeavor to mathematically model the seven tiebreaker steps for wild cards. I'd bet that historically, the actual chances are approximately 22%. I'll check when I get to my pc.